# How to aggregate data inserted by users to avoid outliers?

Tags: data, outlier, aggregation

I'm developing a new application based on machine learning. In this application users can insert new data to improve the prediction system.
As you may guess, users could insert data that doesn't make sense, generating in this way outliers that may harm the prediction accuracy.
I'm pretty new to this field so I would like to ask you: do you know any strategy to mitigate this? Maybe by implementing a voting or aggregating system?
In that case, do you have any hint, our could you please direct me to some theoretical topics regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution would be make your data agree to some rules. But, that may not be possible.

You can find the similarity of the new data with the data you already have. It is beyond a certain threshold then that data doesn't make sense.

You can also use the data directly for training and find it using techniques like [TracIn](https://ai.googleblog.com/2021/02/tracin-simple-method-to-estimate.html) but this may readily usable.

Your best bet is second method of finding similarity and thresholding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second method seems good, but the kind of data that an user can add in my application is new fresh data that might not be similiar to the data contained in the dataset.

Comment: @zzzz - what about this approach: you train the initial model and observe some key metric - lets call it baseline. then after user inputs new data, you retrain your model and compare new metric with your baseline. if new model performs better, you keep the inputted data, if not - you reject this new user data and keep initial dataset unchanged and ideally show a message in the UI that inputted data hasn't improved the performance.

Comment: if the amount of data flowing in is less and model trains fast enough, that is good. otherwise, you need to validate that data somehow.